# how to get the previous value of a version column in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a version column  named comment .I have to fetch the previous value of this column so that i can compare it with the current value.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the version history using '/_layouts/15/versions.aspx'. Below code block may help you. I have tried to put my comments on your understanding. Please try and let me know if it works.

Note: Please make sure to add required jQuery file references while testing the code. [Ref](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a66e3a5a-1cc2-4a7f-8f67-993745ff3dc0/how-to-fetch-list-column-values-from-version-history-using-jsom-or-rest?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

```
function getItemVersions(url, listId, itemId, success) {
    var versionsUrl = url + '/_layouts/15/versions.aspx?list=' + listId + '&ID=' + itemId;
    $.get(versionsUrl, function(data) {
        var versionEntries = parseVersionList(data);
    });
}


function parseVersionList(data) {
    var entries = {};
    var html = $.parseHTML(data);
    var versionList = $(html).find('table.ms-settingsframe');

    versionList.find('tbody > tr').each(function(i) {
        if (i > 0 && (i - 1) % 2 == 0) {
            var verRow = $(this); //get version row
            var propsRow = verRow.next(); //get properties row
            var versionLabel = verRow.find('td:first').html().trim();

            //get item properties from propsRow goes here
        }

    });
    return entries;
}


//Usage
var webUrl = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com"; // Need to be changed
var listId = "{2697fad3-57d8-455c-8a49-59a065b08b31}"; // Need to be changed
var listItemId = 3; // Need to be changed
getItemVersions(webUrl, listId, listItemId, function(versionEntries) {
    console.log(versionEntries);
});
```